# Find ul with a specific li item in a collection of ul and than add class to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a collection of unordered lists. I would like to iterate through this list and than find an specific li item and than add a class to the ul containing that li.

I hope I was clear enough for you guys. Let me show you my code for better understanding.

This is a fiddle I created to help you understand my problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/wdwn9swu/

This is what I tried to target the ul I need but it didn't work.

```
if ($('ul.sub-tab').find('ul.sub-tab > li.super-active')) {
        $('ul.sub-tab').find('li.super-active').addClass('super-active');
    }
```

I would like that on of the lists that corresponds with the id, to always be open.
Any idea guys ?? Thanks!!

Comment: `$('ul.sub-tab > li.super-active').parent().addClass('super-active');`

Comment: This works, thank. What about in the cases that the list is 3-levels deep? .parent() will only take the first parent of that li right?

Comment: Yes it will, if you want to assign that class on all ancostor `<ul>`s, please update your question and i will update my answer.

Comment: @dave please answer the question so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest and simplest way is:

`$("li.super-active").parent().addClass("super-active");`

According the fact you are using valid html `<li>` element parent must be `<ul>` element in that case (can also be `<ol>`).

```js
$('.main-tab>li a').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.sub-tab').slideToggle(200);
  $(this).parent().siblings('li').children('.sub-tab').slideUp(200);
});

$('.main-tab li').each(function() {
  id = '10';
  $links = $(".main-tab li[data-id =" + id + "]");
  $links.addClass("super-active");
  //console.log("1234");
});

$("li.super-active").parent().addClass("super-active");

 console.log($(".super-active"));
```

```css
.main-tab ul {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.sub-tab {
  display: none;
}

.super-active img {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">

  <ul class="main-tab">

    <li data-id="5">
      <a href="#">Main 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-tab">
        <li data-id="7">
          <a href="#">Main 1 Sub 1</a>
          <ul class="sub-tab">
            <li data-id="10"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            <li data-id="11"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">Main 1 Sub 2</a>
          <ul class="sub-tab">
            <li data-id="12"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            <li data-id="13"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    <li data-id="8">
      <a href="#">Main 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-tab">
        <li data-id="9">
          <a href="#">Main 2 Sub 1</a>
          <ul class="sub-tab">
            <li data-id="14"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            <li data-id="15"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    <li data-id="3">
      <a href="#">Main 3</a>
      <ul class="sub-tab">
        <li data-id="25">
          <a href="#">Main 3 Sub 1</a>
          <ul class="sub-tab">
            <li data-id="17"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            <li data-id="18"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

Comment: I cannot accept your answer since dave gave it first. Sorry but thanks a lot

Comment: It&#39;s okay, I like to contribute to the community. Anyway please notice that my answer is not the same as Dave gave.

Comment: Of course I noted that, just that the answer @dave provided was also the right one, which could solve my problem also. :) Once  again thank you a lot for the time.

Comment: I will accept you answer since @dave did not answerd it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`:has`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

> Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the
>   specified selector.

Find `ul.sub-tab` that has a list item with `.super-active` class, and add the class `.super-active` to the ul as well:

```
$('ul.sub-tab:has(li.super-active)').addClass('super-active');
```

**Example:**

```js
$('ul.sub-tab:has(li.super-active)').addClass('super-active');
```

```css
.sub-tab.super-active {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">

  <ul class="main-tab">

    <li data-id="5">
      <a href="#">Main 1</a> 
      <ul class="sub-tab"> <!-- this will be removed -->
        <li data-id="7" class="super-active">
          <a href="#">Main 1 Sub 1</a>
          <ul class="sub-tab">
            <li data-id="10"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            <li data-id="11"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">Main 1 Sub 2</a>
          <ul class="sub-tab">
            <li data-id="12"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            <li data-id="13"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    <li data-id="8">
      <a href="#">Main 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-tab">
        <li data-id="9">
          <a href="#">Main 2 Sub 1</a>
          <ul class="sub-tab">
            <li data-id="14"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            <li data-id="15"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    <li data-id="3">
      <a href="#">Main 3</a>
      <ul class="sub-tab">
        <li data-id="25">
          <a href="#">Main 3 Sub 1</a>
          <ul class="sub-tab">
            <li data-id="17"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            <li data-id="18"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

Comment: This has two different ul open. I only need the ul with the specific element.

Comment: I've changed the demo to add a background to the ul that has a list item with the `.super-active` class.

Comment: I see, but main2 and main3 must not be opened. @oridrori

Comment: I didn't take all the functionality from your code, just the part that demonstrates my solution to your question. Try it in your own code.